# Many to Many relationship in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a Users model and a Chats model. Intuitively multiple people will belong to the same chat group at any time and each person can have many chat groups. Therefore the chat group must belong to multiple `user_id`'s.

My schema for the chat group and users are:

```
schema "chatGroups" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :messages, Message
    belongs_to :user, User

    timestamps
end

schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :chatGroups, ChatGroup

    timestamps
end
```

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is an old question and the previously accepted answer was no longer the de facto way.

Ecto now supports HABTM or many to many associations.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3

```
many_to_many :users, MyApp.User, join_through: "chat_group_users"
```

Comment: this should be the preferred way to do many to many using ecto

Comment: The documentation focuses mostly on bulk updates and edits of nested data. But how to add a person to a chat group? Since intermediate schema for "chat_group_users" is not defined and we don't want to allow people update anything else, but just link both together. It should be a simple insert into "chat_group_users" table, but I cant find anything in Ecto that can do this without bulk editing (put_assoc) or creating the chat_group_users schema.

Answer (score 34):

Ecto has support for [has_many/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) through relationships. This involves creating an intermediate table between your chat groups and your users.

You can do this with the following schema:

chat_group.ex:

```
schema "chat_groups" do
  has_many :chat_group_users, MyApp.ChatGroupUser
  has_many :users, through: [:chat_group_users, :user]
end
```

chat_group_user.ex:

```
schema "chat_group_users" do
  belongs_to :chat_group, MyApp.ChatGroup
  belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
end
```

You can also do the association the other way:

user.ex:

```
schema "users" do
  has_many :chat_group_users, MyApp.ChatGroupUsers
  has_many :chats, through: [:chat_group_users, :chat]
end
```

This allows you to do things like:

```
Repo.get(Chat, 1) |> Repo.preload(:users)
```

This will fetch the users for your chat model and populate the `:user` key with the value.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require making a join table. Oh well. Thanks for the clarification! I'll investigate it this weekend and accept once I have done so.

Comment: This works except the syntax for me was: `through: [:chat_group_users, :chat]` (notice the colon in front of the first param and the comma afterwards,)

Comment: Chowza, the nice thing about doing it explicitly this way is that you can set your join table to have foreign key reference with :delete_all so that the join table cleans itself up when associated records are deleted.

Comment: Is it possible to add conditions to the association?